# run pipline when project is push in github

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

i write this pipline in jenkines file for automatic ci/cd in my project for every time my project push on github:

i using this trigger `triggers {githubPush()}` .

```
pipeline{
    triggers {
        githubPush()
    }
    agent any 
    stages{
        stage('Install  npm'){
            steps{
                sh "npm install"
            }
          }
}
```

now when i push the project its not doing any thing .

whats the problem ? how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: `Trigger that runs jobs on push notifications from GitHub.`. Did you set up push notifications from GitHub to your Jenkins?

Comment: @MaratC i just write this code for push notification

Comment: Ok, you need to set up push notifications on github then.

Comment: @MaratC thank you . i try that

Comment: are you sure, githubPush() is a valida parameter for `triggers {}` DSL ?
But I don't think its a valid option. take a look at [this](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#triggers) documentation. it only supports `crone`, `pollSCM`, and `upstream`

Comment: @SamitKumarPatel . thank you . it worked